# How to convert date format using python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to convert the date format from `Wed Aug 16 2017` to `16/08/2017`

Here is the code I tried:

```
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(newList[0], '%a %b %d %Y').date()
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(str(datetime_object), '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d/%m/%y')

print datetime_object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import datetime
dateTime = datetime.datetime.strptime("Wed Aug 16 2017", "%a %b %d %Y")
print dateTime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

This gives you datetime object object, out of that you can format it however you want

Comment: My input for date is Wed Aug 16 2017. Please see the input properly